# Cannot override template provided by contrib module in theme

Tags: 8, theming

I'm leveraging the [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) module for our menus but need to tweak the output a bit.
Normally I'd just copy the relevant template file (in this case `superfish-menu-items.html.twig`) into my theme and call it a day.
This isn't working in this case. Any ideas why that might be and how to get around it?

Before voting to close this issue, I'd ask that you request information you think would be valuable to providing additional specificity.
I can only assume that this issue is due to some issues with the construction of the Superfish module itself and its theming implementation, so I'm trying to figure out how to work around this.
Any solution would likely be applicable in similar contexts as well.

I've tried modifying the element in `hook_theme()` and `hook_theme_registry_alter()` to point to my theme's implementation of the template, but in both cases I end up hitting

> Twig_Error_Loader: Template is not defined errors.

**EDIT:** I'd already enabled debugging prior to posting. Please stop suggesting that I enable debugging. This is what is shown before and after copying the template into my theme. I've cleared caches and verified the template name in my theme.[image]

Comment: Did you rebuild cache?

Comment: Yes I rebuilt the cache and doublechecked the naming.

Comment: Do you have debug enabled? It will tell you what file is being used [Debugging Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)

Comment: Yes, I have debugging enabled and it shows the default implementation being used instead of the version in my theme.

Comment: i have tested it, it works just copy/past `superfish-menu-items.html.twig` to `templates` folder (Not root folder) of your theme, and flush caches it will work.

Comment: @berramou your testing must have pleased the Drupal gods. Inexplicably working on my end now as well. Guess I just needed to clear the cache 1000 times.

Answer (score -3):

For drupal8 you need to enable twig debug in the service.yml file. Then clear cache. After that, you will see in the browser inspector all templates name suggestion to override a part of the page.